# Creating Drawer-like window

Tags: c++, winapi, controls

How do you create a window that is attached to the side of parent window opens like a drawer?
In such a way that you don't lose focus of parent window.

Answer (score 0):

What you basically need to do is create yourself a custom control representing your drawer. I'm not sure if that's something you're familiar with or not, but if not there are plenty of tutorials about, such as [this one](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/custctrl).

I imagine what you'd do is designate part of your control to be the "handle", which if clicked upon "opens" the drawer. You would achieve this by handling the WM_LBUTTONDOWN/WM_LBUTTONUP messages in your control's window procedure, and changing its size from its closed size to its open size when clicks are detected. I haven't used it before, but you might be able to simply achieve animation using [AnimateWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You'd probably also want to have your control send it's parent window a notification whenever it is opened or closed, so that your parent window can re-size or move other controls if necessary. You can achieve this by sending a WM_NOTIFY message to the parent window with your own notification code, or using your own custom message. Your parent window would then have to respond to such messages in its window procedure.

As far as I'm aware there's no specific examples to be found addressing your exact requirements, so I probably can't supply much more info at the moment. If there's anything else in particular you need to know to get this running, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Are custom window and custom control the same? I'd place a richedit control but shouldn't it be over a window?

Comment: @user32344: No, a custom window and a custom control are not the same thing, although they are very similar. And, I'm sorry but I'm not following where you're going with the richedit control.

Comment: Sorry, I mean for placing other window controls on a drawer, I'd need a custom window rather than a custom control, right?